# How to Use google-auth-library with Vite?

Tags: javascript, vite, bundler, google-auth-library

When importing library error is thrown in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null.............google-auth-library.js`

Here's a StackBlitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-1hhasb?file=src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev

New to bundlers as Vite so maybe I miss something in docs, but not clear of way to load such a common library.

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509548/google-auth-library-import-issues-with-vite-react-project) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370050/jwt-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor-or-null-in-google-auth-li) is the same issue but Typescript.

Comment: `google-auth-library` is a *`node.js` client library* - you seem to want to use it in a browser - also, the stackblitz you linked to doesn't produce any error, so, not sure what use it is

Comment: @JaromandaX the link does reproduce the error. The UI is never drawn and the console displays the error. though you do raise a good point. i think i need to try `gapi-client` instead

Comment: chrome shows it too